# Looping by row, and then by column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops, rows

I need to loop by row (within a column) and then by the remaining columns in the data set.

I already tried using iterows(), iloc(), and iat().

```
import pandas as pd

# Two-dimensional data frame
table = {'A' : [0.1, -0.2, 0.3, -0.4],'B' : [-0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8], 'C' : [0.3, -0.6, -0.9, -1.3]}

# Setting index to be new column
df = pd.DataFrame(table, index = ['W','X','Y','Z'])

column_list = list(df.columns)
total_columns = len(column_list)

total_rows = len(df.index)

column_num = 1
column = column_list[column_num]


winners = []
losers = []
zero = []   


for col_num in df: 
    row_num = 1
    for row_num in df:
        if (df.iloc[row_num][column]) > 0:
            winners.append(df.iloc[row_num][column])

        elif (df.iloc[row_num][column]) < 0:
            losers.append(df.iloc[row_num][column])

        else:
            zero.append(df.iloc[row_num][column])

        row_num = row_num + 1
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: If I am reading this correctly, you just want to make a list from all of the elements of your dataframe, beginning with the first index fir element and ending with the last index last element correct?

Comment: I want to iterate by row in column, then repeat the number of columns.

Comment: result of each column will become an entry in another dataframe

Answer (score 1):

You can use iterrows, and do this in a list comprehension.

```
In [11]: [x for _, col in df.iteritems() for x in col]
Out[11]: [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 1.3]
```

or you can flatten the numpy array:

```
In [12]: list(df.values.T.flatten())
Out[12]: [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 1.3]
```